# OperationalError: 2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '119.82.95.216' (timed out)" when trying to connect Heroku app to local mysql server

Tags: python, mysql, heroku, flask

I am trying to connect a local MySQL server to my Heroku app. I have passed my IP address as the host parameter. Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
app = Flask(__name__)

mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'XXXX'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'XXXX'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = '119.82.95.216'


mysql.init_app(app)
conn = mysql.connect()
cursor = conn.cursor
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

> pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server
>   on '119.82.95.216' (timed out)")

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: are you sure that your 'local'(119.82.95.216) port is not closed (firewall) or behind a router? try connecting to `119.82.95.216` using some mysql client first, for check errors

Comment: I tried connecting through MySQL workbench, but it didn't work. Here is the error I got: Can't connect to MySQL server on '119.82.95.216' (60). What I am supposed to enter as the host parameter to make this work.

Comment: you will never be able to connect to your local database because your isp might be blocking incoming connection at all your ports. Do you have a static ip? are you behind a router?

Comment: Yes, I do have a static IP. If I can't to my local database, is there any other alternative that I can use?

Comment: use a database on heroku instance, check [this](https://medium.com/@dushan14/create-a-web-application-with-python-flask-postgresql-and-deploy-on-heroku-243d548335cc)

Comment: "I am trying to connect a local MySQL server to my Heroku app"—this is backwards. _Clients_ connect to _servers_. Why do you want to use a local database?

Comment: My bad regarding the reverse thing. I am using a local database because I want to store all the info (or at least have access to it) on my computer. If there are any other good ways, I am open to using them.

Comment: @ARJUNAGGARWAL, as waynetech suggests the solution is to use a database that's hosted in the cloud. Nothing is stopping you from accessing the data it contains on your local machine.